# Engineering/Construction question in the wake of climate change, whereto with it?

Tags: support

Recently, two papers where published independently documenting accelerated mass loss of Greenland's glaciers, namely https://www.nature.com/articles/s43247-020-0010-1 and https://www.nature.com/articles/s43247-020-0001-2.

How would, for instance, the Netherlands cope with a 1m sea level rise in a few decades? Parts are below sea level anyway. Is there a department in SE where the question would be appropriate?

Comment: Nevermind, found my answer. They'd have to run from more than half a meter in 30 years.

Comment: Your question is interesting and readers who find it in the future may appreciate you posting at least a short answer. It's always okay to answer your own question in SE and nothing wrong with accepting the answer if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), which at first glimpse seems to be suitable for questions like this: it has tags like `civil engineering` and `geotechnical engineering`. However, [a similar question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/in-what-ways-could-coastal-cities-like-new-york-boston-miami-mitigate-future-sea) has been closed for being too broad... It was five years ago though, so it might be worth another shot!